# Multiple fonts in pdfMake for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdfmake

I am working with *pdfMake*, that converts the static text into pdf.

My text in HTML is coming from a service in AngularJS and is dynamic. The text can have both English as well as non-English characters like Korean, Japanese, Chinese, etc.

Currently, I have only English font, so it prints *blank* for the non-English characters.

How can one fix this issue?

The **JS** code:

```
  self.downloadAsPdf = function (dateTimeId) {
      var datetime = document.getElementById(dateTimeId).innerHTML;
      pdfMake.fonts = {
        proximaNova: {
          normal: 'proximanova-regular.ttf',
          bold: 'Roboto-Medium.ttf',
          italics: 'proximanova-light.ttf',
          bolditalics: 'proximanova-semibold.ttf'
        }
      };
      var docDefinition = {
          { text: 'Heading', style: 'header' },
          { text: 'Subheading', style: 'myscript' },
          { text: datetime, style: 'datetime' },
          { text: model.storyScriptData.personalMoment, style: 'body' }, 
          { text: model.storyScriptData.createAConnection, style: 'body' },                
          { text: model.storyScriptData.theResoultion, style: 'body' }
        ],
        defaultStyle: {
          font: 'proximaNova'
        },
        styles: {
          header: {
            fontSize: 24,
            alignment: 'center',
            color: "#ffffff",
            margin: [0, 60, 0, 0]
          },
          myscript: {
            fontSize: 18,
            alignment: 'left',
            color: "#a7a7a7",
            margin: [0, 100, 0, 0]
          },
          datetime: {
            fontSize: 11,
            alignment: 'left',
            color: "#a7a7a7",
            margin: [0, 2, 0, 36]
          },
          body: {
            fontSize: 13,
            alignment: 'left',
            color: "#727272",
            lineHeight: 1.5,
            bolditalics: true
          }
        }
      }

      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('optionalName.pdf');
    }
```

where `model.storyScriptData.personalMoment`, `model.storyScriptData.createAConnection` and `model.storyScriptData.theResoultion` are the `model`'s in AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

Suposing that you know which language is being used at each time, and that you can receive it from model on some atribute as `model.storyScriptData.currentLanguage`.

You should have a object similar to:

```
var fonts = {
    english: 'english_font_name',
    japanese: 'japanese_font_name',
    chinese: 'chinese_font_name',
    korean: 'korean_font_name'
}
```

Then you can choose the correct font for each language:

```
    defaultStyle: {
      font: fonts[model.storyScriptData.currentLanguage]
    }
```

You can add custom fonts to your pdfMake instance, as on their documentation [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side). 
Also, explained a bit differently in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46329468/4807130).